# How do I change the default working directory of haskell mode in emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

I am trying to make it so the default working directory of haskell mode updates when I load a module via C-l. Currently, the working directory is always my home directory. This makes it impossible to load custom modules and run them with emacs. Instead, I have to launch them from the command line which isn't horrible but it is more time consuming and a little annoying.

How can I make the working directory update when I use C-l to load a module?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `haskell-mode` then I think you can set a key to `haskell-process-load-file`.
You can see the examples [here](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/blob/master/examples/init.el)